# Windows recovery can't find Windows install

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, raid

I'm trying to repair my boot loader for Windows after a Ubuntu install killed it. I'm trying to use the Windows Repair CD (actually USB stick), but Windows recovery can't find my Windows install. I know that it's there because Linux sees it and the hard drives are not failing.

I think it has something to do with drivers because I am using a RAID configuration. Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks!

EDIT: So I have an "Intel Rapid Storage Technology enterprise" thing controlling my RAID. I downloaded these drivers: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2101&DwnldID=23496&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel®+Rapid+Storage+Technology+(Intel®+RST)&lang=eng

But they didn't do anything. Windows says that they don't contain any information about my hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the driver in WinRE using dism - for example:

Dism /Image:C:\mount\winre /Add-Driver /Driver:"C:\SampleDriver\driver.inf"

in c:\mount\winre is the mounted winre.wim, driver is in c:\SampleDriver

see [Customize Windows RE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825125.aspx#BKMK_AddDrivers)

Comment: Is this from inside Windows RE or before I start to use Windows RE?

Comment: The procedure is changing WinRE from outside - it includes the driver in WinRE so it is available when you start WinRE. Follow the procedure from Microsoft given in link.

Comment: It seems that this only works for Windows 8 and above. Do you know how to do this on Windows 7?

Comment: Dism should be there in Windows 7. Alternative is imagex.exe, see http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/getwaiktools for download.